# copying data from one file to template file not copying to the right columns

Tags: python, pandas, mapping, openpyxl

I am writing a code that selects data from a catalogue file and copies it into a template file without modifying it.

A column ("product type") in the catalogue file determines which sheet it's gonna copy the data into the template file.

Template file column headers (the ones I am mapping to match the catalogue file) are in the 3rd row.
There's some columns in template file that don't have a column in catalogue, so these should have empty values

The data is not being copied into the right column although the mapping names are correct.

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl


# Load the "catalogue" and "template" Excel files
catalogue_file = r"catalogue.xlsx"
catalogue_df = pd.read_excel(catalogue_file , sheet_name="Sheet_all")

template_file = r'template.xlsx'
template_workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(template_file, data_only=True)

# Create a mapping between column names in "catalogue" and "template"
column_mapping = {
    'PRODUCT ID': 'External ID',
    'model': 'Model Number',
    'Attribute1': 'Characteristic', 
    'Description': 'Model Name',
    'PRODUCT TYPE': 'Product Type', 
}

# Create a mapping between "PRODUCT TYPES" and sheet names in "template"
type_to_sheet_mapping = {
    'PRODUCT_TYPE_1': 'Template-type1',
    'PRODUCT_TYPE_2': 'Template-type2',
    'PRODUCT_TYPE_3': 'Template-type3',
}

for index, row in catalogue_df.iterrows():
    product_type = row['PRODUCT TYPE']  
    data_to_copy = row.rename(column_mapping)

    # Check if the product type has a corresponding sheet name in the mapping
    if product_type in type_to_sheet_mapping:
        sheet_name = type_to_sheet_mapping[product_type]
        try:
        # Select the appropriate sheet in the "template" workbook
            template_sheet = template_workbook[sheet_name]
            # Find the last row and increment by 1
            last_row = template_sheet.max_row
            new_row = [last_row + 1] + data_to_copy.tolist()
            # Add the new data to the sheet
            template_sheet.append(new_row)
        except:
            print(f"{product_type} does not have a template sheet")

template_workbook.save(r"updated_template.xlsx")
```

Comment: It looks like the issue lies with dataframe operations, not the read and export phases. A good [mre] could maybe start with a sample of input dataframe, the "mapping" code without the export, and an expected output.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why are you bothering with pandas at all here. You should easily be able to do everything directly in openpyxl.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can maybe first initialize a `new_row` list with None values for all columns in the template file. Then, iterate through the data and copy it to the corresponding columns.

```
# ...

for index, row in catalogue_df.iterrows():
    product_type = row['PRODUCT TYPE']  
    data_to_copy = row.rename(column_mapping)

    # Check if the product type has a corresponding sheet name in the mapping
    if product_type in type_to_sheet_mapping:
        sheet_name = type_to_sheet_mapping[product_type]
        try:
            # Select the appropriate sheet in the "template" workbook
            template_sheet = template_workbook[sheet_name]

            # Find the last row and increment by 1
            last_row = template_sheet.max_row
            new_row = [None] * (len(column_mapping) + 1)  # Initialize with None for all columns
            for col_name, value in data_to_copy.items():
                if col_name in column_mapping:
                    col_index = list(column_mapping.values()).index(column_mapping[col_name])
                    new_row[col_index + 1] = value

            # Add the new data to the sheet
            template_sheet.append(new_row)
        except:
            print(f"{product_type} does not have a template sheet")

# ...
```